# How to change display name of an app in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Apple have [clear instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/qa/qa1823/_index.html) on how to change the display name of an IOS app, but they are not useful for a react-native app because the folder structure is different. How do you change the display name if you have a react-native app?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

### iOS

Goto `ios/<Appname>/Info.plist` and edit the `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` to change the display name

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
```

### Android

Goto `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` and edit the `APP_NAME` to change the name

```
<string name="app_name">APP_NAME</string>
```

Comment: Hi, In the Apple documentation I cited, it tells you to change the ```CFBundleDisplayName ```, whereas your instructions are changing the ```CFBundleName```. What is the difference between these?

Comment: If you are not having `CFBundleDisplayName` in the `Info.plist`, Apple will take the `CFBundleName` as the name of your app. 
`CFBundleDisplayName` is used in the grid of apps on iOS devices.
`CFBundleName` is used in the list of apps stored in iTunes library.

Comment: Worked for me. Remember to uninstall the app from the device and rebuild it to see the name change (android).

Comment: On Android .. the path exactly is `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`

Comment: On iOS I had both `CFBundleName` and `CFBundleDisplayName`, so it only worked after changing each of them.

Answer (score 45):

for **ios** just add this to `Info.plist`

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>APP_NAME</string>
```

for **android** edit `strings.xml` file which located in `res/values/`

```
<string name="app_name">APP_NAME</string>
```

Answer (score 9):

res -> values -> strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name">YOUR APP NAME HERE</string>
```

Change that and you will have changed your display name of the app.

Inside the manifest file, inside the **application** tag you will find

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

You can change this too, if you want to change the display name of your app.

**Note**: It is always recommended to have values stored in the "values" folder instead of hardcoding the values directly.

Comment: Please note that the full path for the `strings.xml` relative the project root is: `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`.

Answer (score 5):

There's a file called app.json in the root of your project. Just change the "displayName" then delete ios folder and run "react-native eject".

Comment: works perfectly without touching platform specific files

Comment: please warning before you're `ejecting` from react native

Answer (score 4):

file path : /android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

replace My App with your app name.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating an app from a template with a Display Name which needs to be changed later, it would be preferable to create the app with the desired names from the start, [as I explain here in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67980741/1154625). For a new app use:

```
npx react-native init NewcoFrameDesign --title "Newco Frame Design"
```

The `--title` option corresponds to the display name in `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` and `ios/NewcoFrameDesign/Info.plist` as well as in app.json.

Comment: That's great when you create, however with most developments you change the name during development.  How do you update and have it reflect in both projects

Comment: There's also an additional `--package-name` flag, which allows to specify a reverse domain name that is not .com based by default.