# How can I change the project and app name of ReactNative project with react-native 0.60

Tags: react-native

It's simple issue but I don't know how to do it. I'm looking for some references, but there are problems.

1. I'm using `react-native : 0.60.5`. Hence there is no `eject` method or command.
2. The project was not created with `expo`.
3. After I referenced [How to Rename A React Native App](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/how-to-rename-a-react-native-app-dafd92161c35) and [error Unrecognized command "eject"](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25526), then I follow the process below.

   - change the `app.json`'s `name` and `diplayName` field to name which I want to change
   - remove `android/` and `ios/` directory
   - use `react-native upgrade --legacy true`

But there is no change on the **project name** and **app name**.

Is there any way to change the **project** and **app** name? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580858/how-to-change-display-name-of-an-app-in-react-native

Comment: @SDushan Yes. I already check it. As I know, that is about **changing the app name(display name)**. I want to change **project name** also. By the way, if I change the **app name** only, the name is also displayed on released app ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the below steps :

if you want to change both the app name and the package name (i.e. rename the entire app), the following steps are necessary:

- Make sure you don't have anything precious (non-generated, manually
  copied resources) in the android/ and ios/ subfolders.
- Delete both the android/ and ios/ folder.
- Change the "name" entry in your package.json to the new name.
- Change the app name in both your index.android.js and index.ios.js:
  AppRegistry.registerComponent('NewAppName', () => App);
- Run react-native upgrade to re-generate the platform subfolders.
- If you have linked resources (like custom fonts etc.) run
  react-native link.
- If you have other generated resources (like app icons) run the
  scripts to generate them (e.g. yo).
- Finally, uninstall the old app on each device and run the new one.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: thanks ! it was big help!. The only difference was that I used `react-native upgrade --legacy true`. And the process of setting android was hell... but I changed the project and app name successfully. Thanks!

Comment: running  react-native upgrade doesn't create ios and android folders

Answer (score 2):

for android edit strings.xml file which located in res/values/

```
string name="app_name">APP_NAME</string
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very hard time with this and this is what I did - hopefully it helps someone. Literally took me 15 minutes

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename install react-native-rename and rename your app to whatever you need using the instructions provided for the package
   Important part would be to use this:
   npx react-native-rename "YourProjectName" -b com.yourporjectnamehere - because this is needed for android to work correctly
2. find in your project every file and folder name that will contain your previous name - for me it was mostly in ios folder. I had to rename all the folders and some of the files inside. just replace the part with your previous name with your current name
3. find all occurrences of your previous name left inside the project with the whole project search in your editor and replace them with the new name.

To make it work for ios

1. Delete Pods inside the ios folder
2. Delete node_modules
3. go to ios folder with your terminal and do pod install
4. do npm install in your original directory again
5. make sure all the caches are deleted for your ios simulator with yarn start --reset-cache

To make it work for android

1. Make sure that under android/app/src/com/yourprojectnamehere/ the folder contains MainApplication.java and MainActivity.java files and that the project name inside are updated
2. ./gradlew clean inside android folder in terminal
3. Delete node_modules
4. npm install
5. react-native run-android and everything should be working

I know its a lot of steps, but from what I have found renaming react native app is not actually as easy as you might have thought