# How do you change the "Display Name" of a React Native app in XCode?

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, bundle-identifier

I have a React Native app that has Display Name `theApp`:

[image]

I want to change it to `The App`. However, I'm hesitant to just change it in that box in XCode because there are now instances of `theApp` elsewhere in the autogenerated code, and in the Bundle Identifier etc.

Has anyone changed a Display Name like this before? Do you know how I should approach it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change display name of an app in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580858/how-to-change-display-name-of-an-app-in-react-native)

Comment: You can safely change display name property. And this is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580858/how-to-change-display-name-of-an-app-in-react-native.

Comment: You guys are correct. This is a duplicate of that question. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to edit the name in your targets (what you have in the picture) if that's not working for you I recommend changing the name in the app.json file in your react native project.

Comment: I didn't try changing the name there yet because one of the other commenters pointed out there's an article that shows how to do it in Info.plist, and I don't want to try anything else that could break anything. Thanks for your insight!