# How to set the Display Name when creating a React Native project from a template?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, rename

According to the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#creating-a-new-application) the way to create a React Native project from the default template is as follows:

```
npx react-native init NewcoFrameDesign
```

This will set *NewcoFrameDesign* as the app name in several places in the project including `app.json` as `name` and `displayName`, which is used as the basis for app naming inside the iOS and Android projects.

I want my Display Name to be "Newco Frame Design" (with the spaces) in all relevant locations, as this is used for example in `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` as well as `ios/NewcoFrameDesign/Info.plist` and thereby possibly shown to the user. Using a name with spaces with `react-native init` is not an option, as it will lead to errors.

Having to [rename the Display Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830046/renaming-a-react-native-project) in several places after creating the project from a template should not be necessary.

Therefore, what is the correct way to create a React Native project from a template with a `name` such as *NewcoFrameDesign* and a different `displayName` such as *Newco Frame Design*?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the answer when learning how to make [my own sample template](https://github.com/chriswayg/react-native-minimal-app).

TL;DR The answer is:

`npx react-native init NewcoFrameDesign --title "Newco Frame Design"`

Unexpectedly `--title` corresponds to `displayName` in app.json:

```
{
  "name": "NewcoFrameDesign",
  "displayName": "Newco Frame Design"
}
```

This should have been very easy to find, but the terminology used by React Native is not consistent, so I missed it at first when checking: `npx react-native init --help`:

```
Options:
  --version <string>    Shortcut for `--template react-native@version`
  --template <string>   Uses a custom template. Valid arguments are the ones supported by `yarn add [package]` or `npm install [package]`, if you are using `--npm` option
  --npm                 Forces using npm for initialization
  --directory <string>  Uses a custom directory instead of `<projectName>`.
  --title <string>      Uses a custom app title name for application
  --skip-install        Skips dependencies installation step
  -h, --help            output usage information
```

The use of "*a custom app title*" is not explained in the official documentation and a Google search will not yield helpful results either. Even the  [`react-native-community/cli` source code](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/search?q=title) is confusing as terms like `placeholderName`, `placeholderTitle`, `projectTitle` and `displayName`are used with unclear differentiation. The [React Native templating source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/template.config.js) does provide a clue:

```
placeholderName: 'HelloWorld',
titlePlaceholder: 'Hello App Display Name'
```

The official React Native templates update the `displayName` as specified by `title` in `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` as well as `ios/NewcoFrameDesign/Info.plist` and possibly other places. These determine the app name shown to the user.

Each template should properly specify the `titlePlaceholder` in [template.config.js](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/init.md#creating-custom-template), but [many templates fail to do this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript/blob/master/template.config.js)

```
module.exports = {
  // Placeholder name that will be replaced in package.json, index.json, android/, ios/ for a project name.
  placeholderName: 'CustomReactNativeTemplate',

  // Placeholder title that will be replaced in values.xml and Info.plist with title provided by the user.
  titlePlaceholder: 'Custom React Native Template',
};
```

Not specifying titlePlaceholder leads to the wrong displayName in app.json. It's a minor issue though as the displayName in app.json is only used by the `eject` command. Even if titlePlaceholder is missing in the template config, the `react-native init --title` option will still be properly applied to the ios and android projects.